# Завершение текущего сеанса в firebase при бездействии

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, auth

Не могу понять в документации к FireBase указано, что при бездействии 30 минут происходит завершение текущего сеанса. Данное время можно изменить методом `setSessionTimeoutDuration()`. Как я понимаю проверку на авторизованного пользователя необходимо производить методом `currentUser`. Проблема в том, что даже через сутки этот метод не возвращает null, т.е автоматически не происходит завершение сеанса. Подскажите я не правильно понимаю документацию? Или автоматическое завершение не работает? Или как то по другому необходимо проверять авторизацию пользователя? Или только самому запускать таймер и через определенное время делать принудительный выход с помощью `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, оказывается у firebase нет автоматического прерывания сессии. Описание по прерыванию сессии относится к аналитике. Автоматическое прерывание необходимо писать самому